# Selenium - Falta de permissão para Download

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Criei um script em Python usando o Selenium para acessar um site e fazer o download de alguns arquivos, porém, o navegador bloqueia o download e informa a seguinte mensagem: "Não foi possível baixar - Não há permissões". Obs: Não possuo conta de adm no computador que executo, mas o bloqueio só acontece quando utilizo o Selenium. Se eu abrir o navegador manualmente os downloads são feitos normalmente.

Há alguma opção de ajuste no código para tratar esse bloqueio de downloads (por exemplo, alguma opção no "Options")?
Segue abaixo  uma parte do código como exemplo, mas o erro de permissão acontece em qualquer página/site.

```
def baixa_relacao():
    options = EdgeOptions()
    options.use_chromium = True
    driver = Edge(options=options)
    actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

    driver.get('confidencial')

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsft_nav"]/div/magellan-favorites-list/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/a/div[2]/span').click()


    driver.switch_to.frame('gsft_main')
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Enviar Segurado...').click()

    botao = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hdr_sc_req_item"]/th[5]/span/a')
    actionChains.context_click(botao).perform()

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="context_list_headersc_req_item"]/div[13]').click()

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="d1ad2f010a0a0b3e005c8b7fbd7c4e28_sc_req_item"]/div[2]').click()

    driver.find_element_by_id('download_button').click()
```

Comment: Você já fez essa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/521708/edge-download-com-selenium) não tem como o responder sem saber  a qual página que esse código é destinado.

Comment: Independente da página, ele bloqueia o download. Ou seja, se o script entrar no google e tentar baixar algo, vai dar o mesmo problema de permissão. Eu já tentei em diversas páginas. O código acima foi só uma das páginas de exemplo.

Comment: Mas como assim independente de página, o xpath é bem específico ele só pode ser aplicado aa arvore cujo qual foi projetado.

Comment: O código que coloquei acima é só uma parte do script que acessa determinado site e faz o download de um arquivo. O script acessa outras páginas na internet também para fazer download de outros arquivos. Independente do site ou do navegador que eu usar eu não consigo fazer nenhum download de arquivo e eu recebo a mensagem de "Não há permissões". Eu já tentei inclusive mudar a pasta onde os downloads são salvos, mas também sem sucesso.

Answer (score -3):

Utilize um **User-Agent**, por exemplo:

```
header = {'User-Agent': "Coloque seu User-Agent aqui"}
```

Depois insira no parâmetro no **driver.get**, assim:

```
driver.get('confidencial', headers=header)
```

---

Obs.: para conseguir seu User-Agent basta pesquisar algum site pelo termo "My User-Agent".